# Is it possible to call nls parameters from a model?

Tags: r, parameters, nls

I've used "nls" to fit a logistic equation to some Drug-Receptor binding data;

```
Y= 100/(1+B*Exp(-k*X))
```

The process seems to have worked well (see graph)

[image: nls fit of drug-receptor binding data]

I have the estimates of B and k (the constants from my equation) and I want to use these to estimate the Log EC50 value for the agonist (drug). I can do that easily with a rearrangement of the equation, when `Y=50`, `X=ln(1/B)/-k.` The problem I have is getting the values of `B` and `k` into that rearranged equation- how do I call the parameters (`B` and `k`) from the `nls` model that estimated them for me?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Normally you'd do things liek this with the `predict()` function.

Comment: A note - if you want to get confidence intervals for this quantity you might want to research the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `coef()`.

Try

```
with(as.list(coef(model)),log(1/B)/(-k))
```

as a shortcut for

```
cc <- coef(model)
log(1/cc["B"])/(-cc["k"])
```

Comment: Sorry Ben, I was trying -honest! but it kept telling me that I couldn't accept an answer for another three minutes. I've now accepted the answer. Thanks again for your help.